# How do I set a plugin on CKEditor when is used from the CDN?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, text-editor

I followed the steps on [the CDN Guidelines page for CKEditior](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/), but I can't make it work. The plugin that I'm trying to install is "autoembed" (or any plugin that lets me insert a video from YouTube, a Tweet and all of those different content types), but even when I tried different ways, I can't get it to work.

I was also reading [the documentation on using a custom config file](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-using-a-custom-configuration-file), where apparently they let you create a custom config `config.js` file, but it too doesn't work, or I'm not qualified to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a method in `CKEDITOR.resourceManager` called [`addExternal`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal). You can use it like

```
// Loads a plugin from '/myplugin/samples/plugin.js'.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );
```

Then simply add autoembed to [`config.extraPlugins = 'autoembed'`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins) like

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );

CKEDITOR.replace( 'element', {
    extraPlugins: 'sample'
} );
```

or in `config.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.plugins = 
        'sample,' +
        ...    
};
```

Comment: But, sorry if my question is silly but... Which file i have to modify? I mean, Where is the file that i have to modify and where i have to put that code? I'd understand that is the config.js, right? Thanks for help me!

Comment: @WilliamRomero Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks @oleq I'm honestly grateful! I'll try it right now! You don't know how much you helped me, because i was stuck with that since a few days with none results.

Comment: Hey, guys i'm also stuck, what does 'element' represent ?in replace('element'