# Can't use youtube plugin in CDN CKEditor

Tags: javascript, youtube, ckeditor, cdn

I want to add youtube plugin in CDN CKEditor, I follow the steps from the doc below

[How do I set a plugin on CKEditor when is used from the CDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024196/how-do-i-set-a-plugin-on-ckeditor-when-is-used-from-the-cdn)

Before adding youtube plugins, textarea looks fine

[image]

But after adding youtube plugins, it shows nothing.

My code look like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
....
....
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="article_content">Content：</label>
   <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="article_content"></textarea>
</div>
....
....
....
 <script>
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'youtube', '../public/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/', 'plugin.js' );
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'article_content', {
       extraPlugins: 'youtube'
    });
 </script>
```

Hope someone can give me some advises to fix this problem,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a browser console, you'll find the following:

> Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "youtube" was not
>   found at
>   "https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full/../public/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js?t=H8DA".

It appears that with relative paths, CKEditor searches for the plugin inside the CDN. So, instead use absolute paths and CKEditor will search inside your web server, for example if `public` is inside web server root folder, use:

`CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'youtube', '/public/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/', 'plugin.js' );`

Comment: Hi @Wizard , thanks for your answer. But in my case, I downloaded youtube plugin ( https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube ) in my project. It's absolute path is:  my_project/public/ckeditor/plugins/youtube. It means I use CEKditor from CDN but want to add plugins from local

Comment: Then, you should have: `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'youtube', '/my_project/public/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/', 'plugin.js' );`

Comment: @Wizard I am getting this error as well. In my case it is trying to fetch plugin.js from my localhost webserver (http://localhost:8777/path/I/gave/plugin.js. But I want to read plugin from local node_modules directory